# XSLT select value of if value in node exists

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to select a value with XLST if a value in a node is found. I don't have any experience with XSLT but I need this for a process in Microsoft BizTalk.

So an example of what I would like to do:

```
<STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress>
     <AD_0_StreetAddress>Street 1</AD_0_StreetAddress>
     <AD_1_OtherDesignation>AD_1_OtherDesignation_0</AD_1_OtherDesignation>
     <AD_2_City>City 1</AD_2_City>
     <AD_3_StateOrProvince>Provence 1</AD_3_StateOrProvince>
     <AD_4_ZipOrPostalCode>ZIP 1</AD_4_ZipOrPostalCode>
     <AD_5_Country>Country 1</AD_5_Country>
     <AD_6_AddressType>TYPE 1</AD_6_AddressType>
    <AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>OtherGeographicDesignation 1</AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>
</STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress>
<STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress>
    <AD_0_StreetAddress>Street 2</AD_0_StreetAddress>
    <AD_1_OtherDesignation>OtherDesignation 2</AD_1_OtherDesignation>
    <AD_2_City>City 2</AD_2_City>
    <AD_3_StateOrProvince>Province 2</AD_3_StateOrProvince>
    <AD_4_ZipOrPostalCode>Zip 2</AD_4_ZipOrPostalCode>
    <AD_5_Country>Country 2</AD_5_Country>
    <AD_6_AddressType>AddressType 2</AD_6_AddressType>
    <AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>OtherGeographicDesignation 2</AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>
</STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress>
```

If value `<AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>OtherGeographicDesignation 2</AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation>` exists, select  `<AD_0_StreetAddress>Street 2</AD_0_StreetAddress>`. The only thing is, the sequence is not always the same and node  `<STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress>` can occur 11 times in the same file.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress[
  AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation = 'OtherGeographicDesignation 2'
]/AD_0_StreetAddress
```

Reads as

- of any *office/home address*... (`//STF_11_OfficeHomeAddress`)
- ...that has its *other geographic designation* at a certain value... (`[AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation = 'OtherGeographicDesignation 2']`)
- ...select the *street address*. (`/AD_0_StreetAddress`)

Answer (score 1):

Go through at least the fundamental section of [Jeni Tennison's XSLT tutorial pages](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/index.html) first, you'll then be able to do this yourself by doing push mode (instead of pull mode) and using a predicate with your matching rule such as:

```
<xsl:template match="AD_0_StreetAddress[../AD_7_OtherGeographicDesignation]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: +1 for the tip, although the match expression for the OP wants would still be a little different.